# Function that shows and hides a div when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I'm doing this site that uses a 3d model, with places that I can click to show a message. To achieve this I'm using this: https://modelviewer.dev. It's been working great so far, but I hit a wall right now and I don't know how to fix it.

Here's the code:

```js
const modelViewer2 = document.querySelector("#hotspot-camera-view-demo");
const annotationClicked = (annotation) => {
  let dataset = annotation.dataset;
  modelViewer2.cameraTarget = dataset.target;
  modelViewer2.cameraOrbit = dataset.orbit;
  modelViewer2.fieldOfView = '45deg';
}

modelViewer2.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((hotspot) => {
  hotspot.addEventListener('click', () => annotationClicked(hotspot));
});


function showDiv() {
  const annotationDiv = this.nextElementSibling;

  if (annotationDiv.style.display === "block") {
    annotationDiv.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    annotationDiv.style.display = "block";
  }
}

const items = document.getElementsByClassName('ativador');
Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', showDiv);
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

a {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  font-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.bloco {
  padding: 20px;
}

.eu {
  padding-left: 170px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.link {
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  font-style: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

body {
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 200px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.sobre {
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: start;
}

.cursos {
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  color: #1f1f1f;
  font-size: 21px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  text-align: start;
}

.nome {
  z-index: -1;
}

.bem-vindo {
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.modelo {
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-top: 180px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

model-viewer {
  width: 1495px;
  height: 715px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.hotspot {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: pink;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.hotspot[slot="hotspot-coffee"] {
  --min-hotspot-opacity: .2;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.hotspot[slot="hotspot-calendar"] {
  --min-hotspot-opacity: .2;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.annotation {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  display: none;
}

:not(:defined)>* {
  display: none;
}

.annotation[slot="annotation-sobre"] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(200px, -300px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  font-size: 16px;
  display: none;
}

.annotation[slot="annotation-cursos"] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-600px, -200px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  font-family: "Prompt", "Roboto";
  font-size: 16px;
  display: none;
}

#view-button {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  display: block;
  font-family: Futura, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  max-width: 128px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  height: max-content;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>João Pedro</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/model-viewer/3.1.1/model-viewer.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <model-viewer id="hotspot-camera-view-demo" src="models/scene.gltf" camera-controls touch-action="pan-y" camera-orbit="155deg 75deg 10m">
    <button class="ativador" id="view-button" slot="hotspot-coffee" data-position="-0.85 0.35 -0.8" data-normal="-0.85 0. -0.8" data-orbit="155deg 75deg 0.01m" data-target="-2m 0m 0m">
      Sobre Mim
      <div class="annotation" slot="annotation-sobre">
        <div class = "eu">
          <img src="eu.jpg" alt="Eu...kk" width="100">
        </div>
            <h2 class = "sobre">
                --- Text ---
              </h2>
        </div>
    </button>

    <button class="ativador" id="view-button" slot="hotspot-calendar" data-position="0.35 0.50 -0.4" data-normal="0.35 0.50 -0.4" data-orbit="190deg 85deg 1m" data-target="1.2m 0.1m 3m">
      Cursos & Experiências
      <div onclick = "funcaoTeste" class="annotation" slot="annotation-cursos">
            <h2 class = "cursos">
              --- Text ---
            </h2>
        </div>
    </button>

    <h2 class="nome">João Pedro.</h2>
    <h2 class="bem-vindo">Bem-Vindo <br>ao meu Site.</h2>
    <div class="modelo"><a href="https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/painterly-cottage-0772aec70d584c60a27000af5f6c1ef4" target="_blank"> Modelo Original </a></div>
  </model-viewer>

</body>

</html>
```

My main problem that I'm facing right now it's the buttons, I want then to show a div that it's hidden when I click it. It works for one button, but doesn't work if I add more, in this example, I have 2 buttons, when I click the "sobre" button, for example, it works, but when I click the other one it shows the "sobre" buttons div, instead of the "cursos" one.

I don't know how to fix it anymore, since I'm using the annotation system provided by https://modelviewer.dev <--this, trying to personalizing, I don't know if I'm doing it wrong but it just breaks the hole 3d model and the site.

I tried, `` nextElementSibling, this.parentNode.querySelector('.annotation'); this.closest('.annotation'); document.querySelector(`div[slot="${slot}"]`);const annotationDiv = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('annotation')[0]; ``

None of then have worked, I'm at a lost right know, if you guys could help, would really appreciate.

https://modelviewer.dev/docs/index.html#loading-attributes.
Documentation on the 3d thing if it helps.

Comment: 1st mistake I've noticed, ids must be unique and you have multiple elements with the same id `view-button` in your HTML

Comment: This may not fix anything but one problem I see in your code is that both buttons have the same id. Ids must be unique.

Comment: You are referring to **funcaoTeste** on click on the div, inside of the button. You really should have the button being the triggering element.

Plus you have two event handlers on your buttons.

Comment: @ChrisG Since the JS never refers to that ID, it's an innocuous problem.

Comment: `onclick = "funcaoTeste"` is missing the `()` after the function name, so it doesn't call it. And the function isn't defined in the JavaScript snippet.

Comment: About the onclick, I just forgot to remove it, so that not the main issue here. About the ID stuff I don't think I matters that much in this(I might be wrong though). What I'm struggling most is the actual function to hide the div, the rest is working for now.

Comment: Upon reviewing your code, if I'm looking in the correct place, your showDiv function doesn't actually get the element by id or class.

This could be potentially fixed by giving the annotation div an id field (providing it's unique) then `const element = document.getElementById("annotation");` then the rest of your show div code.